# Add click listener to Buttons in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Beginner here. 
I am using `CursorAdapter` and `ListView`. I have two buttons per row(item?). I would like to add click listener to them such that I can hide/show the `TextViews` it the same row.

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
        TextView arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
        TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);

        String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
        String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
        String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

        arabText.setText(arabic);
        engText.setText(english);
        refText.setText(ref);
    }
}
```

Adapter xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left Button"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;
    private SQLiteDatabase hadlistDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        DatabaseHelper1 hadlistDBHelper;
        hadlistDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper1(this);

        try {
            hadlistDBHelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        hadlistDB =  hadlistDBHelper.openDataBase();

        Cursor todoCursor = hadlistDB.rawQuery("SELECT  ID as _id, * FROM HAD_TABLE WHERE ID < 5 ", null);

        // Find ListView to populate
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        ToDoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new ToDoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);

        todoAdapter.changeCursor(todoCursor);
    }

}
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top2" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I add the listeners to the buttons in adapter xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a button Object on the bindView method you have overridden on the `ToDoCursorAdapter` class then use the findViewById like you use for the the rest of the text view to initialize the object, After which you need to add an onClickListner to do what you have intended on the code (ie. like hiding the textView)

```
public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
    TextView arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

    arabText.setText(arabic);
    engText.setText(english);
    refText.setText(ref);
    //updated
    arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    engText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         { 
           @Override 
           public void onClick(View v){
           arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }

      });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 
           @Override 
           public void onClick(View v){
           engText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
      });
 }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. But I just realized that the GONE part is not reliable. It hides view but when I scroll down I see some other views have been hidden too. Like if I hide it in row 2 then it is hidden for row 4, 6... too. 
Also, when I come back to the top. I see view for that row is now visible and some other view is hidden. 

It is all unpredictable kind. 

Any idea?

Comment: I have updated the answer can you let me know if there is any other issue, It also depends on the logic of how you initally load the status of the visibility. Are you using some local db, an api or shared pref to store the visibility value, If so check for the visibility and update the status on the code that I have updated.

Comment: I am not using anything to store visibility. I used only what I posted initially and then what you suggested. 

Also, the updated code didn't work. I pressed Button for row 1 and then I noticed it hid the `TextView` for row 5, 9, 13 etc. as well. 

Thank you for your response.

Comment: I just now ran you're code on a sample project, It worked as expected but the only issue is, when I scroll down and scroll back up the visibility has changed from GONE -> VISIBLE as expected because it is not persisted between new view creation. So for that purpose you could use local List on the adapter class to keep track of the hidden ones. Or else you need to add a new field to your db and persist the visibility. But I cannot experience your issue, If you want I can upload a video for you, of the sample app

Comment: I will see what I do. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `bindView()` method create `Button` objects and add click listeners to them

```
 @Override public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {   
     Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId); button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {   
              //your code here   
        }   
    });  
}
```

Comment: It seems it is working. I have one question. It will work independently for the Button for each row? I mean, if I click on Button in row 1 it should only do things on row 1 and not anything else. Is it how it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Callback interface

```
public interface ButtonCallback{
     void onClickButton(View v);
     void onClickButton2(View v);
}
```

Your MainActivity implements the Callback interface

```
 public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements ButtonCallback{
   ....
   public void onClickButton(View v){
      // do something
   }

   public void onClickButton2(View v){
      // do something
   }
 }
```

In your Adapter, set the onclicklistener

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
    TextView arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    Button button = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

    arabText.setText(arabic);
    engText.setText(english);
    refText.setText(ref);

    button.setOnClickListenter(new View.OnClickListener({
        public void onCLick(View v){
             context.OnClickButton(v);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListenter(new View.OnClickListener({
        public void onCLick(View v){
             context.OnClickButton2(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

The adapater says can not resolve symbol "OnClickButton" in `context.OnClickButton(v);`

Also, in `Button button = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button);` It should be `Button` and not `TextView`, right? I fixed that one.

Comment: Yeah sorry, copy paste poorly done :/ . Try casting the context to ListViewActivity like this `((ListViewActivity) context).onClickButton(v);`